# MVC 4: Create HTML textboxes dynamically with JQUERY and PartialViewResult. How to fill the model if the code is added dynamically?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am creating form input fields with JQUERY like

```
$('#students').live('change', function () {
  var value = $(this).val();
  if (value) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      timeout: 10000,
       url: "@Url.Action(MVC.Company.ManageWorkReport.GetStudent())",
       data: { studentId: value },
       cache: false,
       success: function (data) {
         if (data) {
           $("#students tbody").html(data);                                
         }
       },
       error: function (xhr, status, error) {
         alert(xhr.responseText);
       }
     });
  }
  return false;
});
```

HTML code to insert data is

```
@using (Html.BeginDefaultForm(MVC.Company.ManageWorkReport.Create()))
{
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered bootstrap-datatable datatable" id="students">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Ime in Priimek</th>
        <th>Vrsta</th>
        <th>Začetek dela</th>
        <th>Konec dela</th>
        <th>Enota</th>
        <th>Cena za enoto</th>
        <th>Količina</th>
        <th>Neto znesek</th>
        <th>Bruto znesek</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="11">Podatek še ne obstaja</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  @Html.SimpleSubmitAndCancelButton(Translations.Global.SAVE, Translations.Global.CANCEL)
}
```

and C#

```
[HttpGet]
public virtual PartialViewResult GetStudent(int studentId)
{
  StudentsWorksReportsFormModel studentsWorksReportsFormModel = new StudentsWorksReportsFormModel();
  .....
  var view = PartialView("StudentWorkReportResult", studentsWorksReportsFormModel);        
  return view;
```

}

Problem is that when I enter data in form and click SUBMIT button model is always empty. Why model is empty if I fill page with JQUERY and later enter data in text fields? How to fill the model also that I can insert data in DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the model binder to pick you new values up you will need to set the name property of the controls.

Each item needs to be indexed and set with the property name.

So for example if your collection was `MyCollection` to set a `Name` property on the first item you would add the following:

```
Name="MyCollection[0].Name"
```

The second etc:

```
Name="MyCollection[1].Name"
```

**[The Features and Foibles of ASP.NET MVC Model Binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx)**

You will need to loop through your collection if you are returning a partial view, something like this:

```
@for(i = 0; i < Model.StudentWorkReportFormModel.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => Model.StudentWorkReportFormModel[i].StartDate})
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I am creating textbox in partial view like

@Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.StudentWorkReportFormModel.StartDate}) How can I override name param if is automatically created?

Comment: @senzacionale No problem, you need to index them so loop through. See my update. :)

Comment: @senzacionale No probs. :)